# How to get a list of open sockets in Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux, networking, sockets, kernel

Is there a way to get a list of all open sockets ( socket address or socket descriptor ) in Linux using C in user-space or kernel?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open and read the following:

`/proc/net/tcp` - a list of open TCP sockets

`/proc/net/udp` - a list of open UDP sockets

`/proc/net/raw` - a list all the "raw" sockets

These are like "regular" files that you open and read with a filehandle and will give you all the information you could possibly need about each socket.

Answer (score 4):

In directory /proc/self/fd there are fake symlinks giving you all your open file descriptors - sockets give something like:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2009-05-08 07:45 4 -> socket:[4921]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2009-05-08 07:45 5 -> socket:[4918]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 2009-05-08 07:45 6 -> socket:[5395]
```

Iterate them using opendir, readdir() and then interrogate them using readlink()

If you know that FD 4 is a socket, you can then call getsockname() on it to get the local address family, address etc, if bound.

Comment: This does not work for all sockets.  Mostly, I see my terminals on here.  With multiple connections open, not all sockets are visible.  Good tool non-the-less to have in addition to what Shane Mason noted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This program may be useful for you and demonstrates how to parse the /net/proc/* files [sockstat.c](http://www.reznor.com/tools/sockstat.c)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I was just going to go through the /proc/self/fd and check which links are sockets and generate the list that way.  I'll post an update with my solution here.  Thanks again

Comment: Link seems to no longer work, though google searches for it finds several copies.

Answer (score 0):

The raw data can be found at /proc/net/tcp, /proc/net/udp, etc. Refer to the header at the first line for a (terse) description.