# Linux kernel programming: list all opened socket file descriptors, and retrieve related information

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, file-descriptor

How should one retrieve all opened socket file descriptors, and other information like socket family, protocol, binding address ?

I need to do this in kernel module, not with some user-land commands...

Comment: You might find [this][1] answer helpful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841714/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-sockets-in-linux-using-c

Comment: @Edmon i must do this in kernel side ... and don't use procfs

Comment: You mean something like sysctl fs.file-nr

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `lsof` (need to be root).

For example : `lsof -i`

You can process the output with AWK or cut.

Hope this help.

Regards.