# C - how to get all IPs connected to my pc

Tags: c, ip

Just as title says. I want to get a list of all IPs connected to my pc. Not the router and not the PCs on the network. Only the IPs which im connected to. I know there is a way in C# but how do you do it in C. 
 I am doing this on a linux.

Comment: Are we talking Linux or Windows OS?

Comment: @OferArial i am talking about linux - let me add that in with an edit

Comment: I tried giving a solution for linux down below.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841876/7276783) links to a program which parses reads from:

```
/proc/net/tcp
/proc/net/udp
/proc/net/raw
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for your IP addresses. To get a list of IP addressess per interface, you can use the `ifconfig` built-in linux functionality, that will output the data and then you can parse it.

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646254/6451874), and based on it, you can use the following code to print each address in a new line:

**Before** you run this, use `locate ifconfig` and set the path in the string accordingly.

**Note my comment:** First check that this command outputs the wanted output for you via the terminal!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  char ip[15];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("ifconfig | grep \"inet addr\" | cut -d\":\" -f2 | cut -d\" \" -f1", "r");

  /*First check that this command outputs the wanted output for you*/
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(ip, sizeof(ip)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", ip);
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```