# Get Information about a socket programmatically

Tags: linux, networking, sockets

When looking at a TCP Socket with /proc/$PID/fd/$FD using readlink I can see it's a socket and a socket number (ID?), e.g.:

```
67 -> socket:[13005]
```

but how am I able to programmatically get actual information for that socket, like `lsof` is doing it? (e.g. hostname or portnumber)

Comment: Do `man 7 socket' and take it from there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841714/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-sockets-in-linux-using-c